# Why is For loop with if statement not working?

Tags: google-apps-script

I was testing the below code to do a particular action when it recognises a string in the first column of the active sheet. The string is "Ticker".

I am getting the below error not sure what it means. Can I please get some help?

```
function extractOrders() {
  
  var app = SpreadsheetApp ;
  var ss = app.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var EndRow = ss.getLastRow()
  
  for (i = 0; i < EndRow; i++) { 
        if (ss.getRange(i, 1).getValue() == "Ticker") { 
         
         Logger.log('ticker found')

        } 
}

}
```

//Error

//Exception: The parameters (String,number) don't match the method signature //for SpreadsheetApp.Spreadsheet.getRange.
//extractOrders @ extractOrders.gs:8

Comment: It's telling you... You are trying to pass `(i, 1)` to `getRange` but it does not accept those parameters. Did you read the documentation?

Answer (score 1):

#### Modification points:

- In your script, `ss` of `var ss = app.getActiveSpreadsheet();` is Spreadsheet object. And you are using the method of `getRange` for this object (Class Spreadsheet). In this case, when the official document of the method `getRange` of Class Spreadsheet, you can see only the method of `getRange(a1Notation)`. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getrangea1notation) Namely, there are no methods of `getRange(row, column)` in Class Spreadsheet. I think that this is the reason of your issue of `The parameters (String,number) don't match the method signature //for SpreadsheetApp.Spreadsheet.getRange.`.
- And also, in your for loop of `for (i = 0; i < EndRow; i++) {`, the start index is `0`. In this case, when `getRange(row, column)` is used, an error occurs. Because the 1st row is `0`. Please be careful this.

In order to avoid these issues, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script 1:

In this pattern, `getRange(a1Notation)` of Class Spreadsheet is used. For this, please set the sheet name to `Sheet1!A${i + 1}`.

```
function extractOrders() {
  var app = SpreadsheetApp;
  var ss = app.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var EndRow = ss.getLastRow()
  for (i = 0; i < EndRow; i++) {
    if (ss.getRange(`Sheet1!A${i + 1}`).getValue() == "Ticker") {
      Logger.log('ticker found')
    }
  }
}
```

#### Modified script 2:

In this pattern, in order to use `getRange(row, column)`, `getRange(row, column)` of Class Sheet is used. When Class Sheet is used, the method of `getRange(row, column)` can be used.

```
function extractOrders() {
  var app = SpreadsheetApp;
  var ss = app.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var EndRow = ss.getLastRow()
  for (i = 0; i < EndRow; i++) {
    if (sheet.getRange(i + 1, 1).getValue() == "Ticker") {
      Logger.log('ticker found')
    }
  }
}
```

- Above script uses the active sheet. When you want to use the specific sheet, please modify `var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();` to `var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2);`.

#### Note:

- In your script, `getValue` is used in a loop. In this case, the process cost will become high. For example, when the number of rows is large, the process time is long. In order to reduce the process cost, as another approach, in order to achieve your goal, I would like to propose to use TextFinder. When TextFinder is used, the process cost will be able to be reduces a little. [Ref](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/0a6f03970b471ffa286f1dac0b79359e) In this sample script, the column "A" of the active sheet is searched.

  ```
    function extractOrders() {
      var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
      sheet.getRange("A1:A" + sheet.getLastRow()).createTextFinder("Ticker").findAll().forEach(r => {
        console.log(`ticker found at ${r.getA1Notation()}`);
      });
    }
  ```

#### References:

- [getRange(a1Notation) of Class Spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getrangea1notation)
- [getRange(row, column) of Class Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer))
- [createTextFinder(findText)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#createTextFinder(String))

Answer (score 0):

The getRange() method requires at least two number which are row and column.  However their are multiple permutations for that method requiring from two to four numbers and then there is the permutation that requires the range string in A1 notation.

[range class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range)

```
function extractOrders() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const rg = sh.getRange(1, 1, sh.getLastRow());
  const vs = rg.getValues();
  vs.forEach((r, i) => {
    if (r[0] == "Ticker") {
      Logger.log("Ticker Found:")
    }
  });
}
```